# Extending functions in mathematica

Tags: function-construction

I am starting with Mathematica and I am willing to use it to perform some cumbersome computations for me.

Specifically, I want to obtain the duals of some convex cones and that requires extending some well-known functions. For instance, the functions

$$y\exp \left(\frac{x}{y} \right) \text{ and } x\log \left(\frac{x}{y} \right)$$

are of my interest and I would like to define $0\exp(\frac{x}{0})=0$ for each $x$ and $0\log(0)=0$, $0\log(\frac{0}{0})=0$, and $x\log(\frac{x}{0})=\infty$.

Can anyone help me to work this out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to accomplish your goal, if I understand it correctly.  For instance,

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, 0] := 0
f[x_, y_] := y Exp[x/y]

f[1, 1]
(* E *)

f[1, 0]
(* 0 *)
```

or

```
Clear[g]
g[x_, y_] := If[y == 0, 0, y Exp[x/y]]

g[1, 1]
(* E *)

g[1, 0]
(* 0 *)
```

The second function in the question can be handled similarly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are interested in is how to attach 'special' definitions for a given function. By this I mean the need to allow eg $y e^\frac{x}{y}$ evaluate normally for all values of $x$ and values of $y$ *other* than $0$ while making it evaluate to $0$ whenever $y$ is $0$ (the other function can be treated in principle with the same approach so it won't be discussed further).

There are more than a handful of ways to achieve such an effect in MA/WL, two of which-the most straightforward *IMHO*-I'll display in what follows.

The first way to achieve the desired effect is to construct a function with different 'branches' for the different cases you are interested in.

To that effect you can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html):

```
f[x_,y_]:=Piecewise[{
  {y e^(x/y), y!=0},
  {0, y==0}},
  $Failed
 ]
```

*A couple of notes on* `f`:

Inputs are *assumed* to be numerical quantities. This is implicit but could be defined more rigorously if that is desired (potential ways to do that with minor adjustments in `f` would include [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)'s on the inputs or incorporating numeric checks (eg using [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)) within `Piecewise` branches-there are still more ways to achieve this eg using [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)).

Related to this is that `f` will return `$Failed` with symbolic inputs for `y`. More rigorous (and probably more demanding) definitions of `f` could involve `Attribute` [`NumericFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericFunction.html) but this is *probably* excessive for the current context.

Finally, similar results can be obtained with [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html).

The second way to achieve similar effects with `f` above, is to make use of how MA/WL uses/matches *patterns*.

When evaluating an expression, all known definions are applied on the input until it no longer changes (this is a simplified way to put it but it suffices for the task at hand).

MA/WL uses *specific* definitions before more general ones during evaluation. To that effect `g[x_,0]=0` is more specific than `g[x_,y_]:=y Exp[x/y]`.

Evaluating these definitions will let MA/WL 'know' that expressions like `g[_,0]` are *more specific* than expressions like `g[a,b]` so when it encounters patterns like the former, it will supply the 'correct' replacement ie $0$ instead of the full definition of $y e^\frac{x}{y}$.

Obviously, numeric constraints and similar considerations to those presented in the first approach are relevant to this approach, too.